# Best method of imputation

Tags: multiple-imputation

I am very new to SPSS and the Statistics package.

I have bi-weekly data on precipitation, air temperature, and several well water temperature (n~75). However, due to various reasons I have about 60-70% of missing values of different dates for the well water temperature value. My goal is to perform cross-correlation but with missing values that is impossible.

The data that I do have shows that there is a linear pattern across time for the each well's water temperature (see figure below). In my attempts to create data, I used imputation, and here is where my knowledge dwindles. I merely chose analyze patterns and then impute missing data using the well water as the imputed data and air temp, and precipitation and date as predictors hoping it would more closely fit the linear pattern of well water temperature over time. I also added minimum and maximum values that are from the data that does exist to constrain the imputed values.

I am trying to figure out which method of imputation is best or if I need to perform some type of regression analysis before I can impute the missing data.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Well water Temperature over time Figure]

Comment: if its specifically a coding question (how do i do imputation in SPSS? etc) this will probably get moved over to stackoverflow. If the question is something more like "which imputation method is appropriate here? how will imputation impact my results? etc then you should clarify your question in this direction.

Comment: Yes sorry, I guess which imputation method is appropriate is what I am looking for.

Comment: Your question is unanswerably vague: Consider "[W]hen I do regular imputation, using the date, air temp, and precipitation as predictors it just seems to give out random values between the constraints I have used...." How did you do your 'regular imputation'? What "constraints"? What do you mean by 'random values?' Are they surprisingly variable? Do they fail to match what you think would be a reasonable regular pattern? Do you think you could do better just guessing on your own? // Imputation almost always involves guesswork. Your thesis may be more believable if you can defend your guesses.

Comment: are you imputing between 2016 and 2019 or beyond 2019 or before 2016?

Comment: Please don't post your question multiple times, because that destroys contributions from other users.

Comment: between 2016 and 2019. And it said it was deleted so I edited and reposted it in order to fit the preferences that the previous comments asked for

Comment: That's a little disingenuous, because *you* deleted the original question!  Please visit our [help] to learn about how this site works.

Comment: Sorry I meant the original was closed.